# How do I beat level 7 hard mode on Lineum on ABCya

Tags: lineum

How do I beat level 7 hard mode on Lineum on ABCya? I have tried to use the help piece and the stone pieces but I still cannot figure it out can someone please help me please?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times.  If you need to add details to your first question, you can [edit it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/404635/edit).